# Can the Outlook object model MailItem object be loaded from a file?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

Using the Outlook object model, is there a way to load an msg file straight out of the filesystem?

And, if so, what is it?

A code snippet for this would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` (documented by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208171%28office.12%29.aspx)).

Hope this helps,